# How do I say "I need some advice about X"?

Tags: translation

For example if I'm going to a wedding in a few weeks, I might ask my friends "I need some wedding clothing advice" or "I need some advice about what to wear".

I know that I can directly ask 参加婚礼穿什么好？or something along those lines, but is there an indirect way to introduce the question? Like the English sentences I wrote above. How could they be naturally translated?

Comment: 我對X不太了解，請您推薦比較好的給我。／我對X拿不定主意，您可不可以給我一點建議？

Comment: 参加婚礼穿什么好 (呢), **请** / **可否** / **能否** / **能不能** 给我一点建议.

Answer (score 2):

In Chinese, what we would naturally say is

> 你知道参加婚礼应该穿什么好吗？

Or even more indirectly

> 你觉得参加婚礼应该穿什么好？

Comment: how about: 征求一下对婚礼穿着的意见

Comment: @user2137196, 你对婚礼穿着有什么建议 sounds more natural.

Comment: @user2137196 This is a more formal way of saying that.

Answer (score 2):

In [I need] [some] [advice] [about X], "**about X**" is an adjectival phrase for the object "**advice**".

*As you can see, the adjectival phrase is placed after the object.*

~

The following is a word for word transfer of English grammar into Chinese sentence:

> [我需要] [一些] [建議], [**關於 X (的)**] - *you need to add adjectival marker '的' to make '關於 X' into an adjectival phrase*

But in native Chinese grammar, the adjectival phrase "關於 X (的)" should be placed before the object "建議" as below:

> [我需要] [一些] [**關於 X (的)**] [建議]

- "我需要一些建議, 關於 X 的." (English grammar)
- "我需要一些關於 X 的建議." (Chinese grammar)

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with Tang Ho

I need some advice about XXX.
我需要一些关于XXX的建议。

I need some advice about what to wear at a friend’s wedding.
我需要关于参加朋友婚礼穿什么的建议。

I need some wedding clothing advice.
我需要一些关于婚礼礼服的建议。(sounds a bit weird I’m told, not very colloquial)

I dunno what I should wear to a wedding.
我不知道参加婚礼应该穿什么。

Can you tell me what’s best to wear to a friend’s wedding?
你可以告诉我去参加朋友婚礼穿什么好吗？